# default passdb backends in Samba

Tags: samba, samba4

The smbpasswd manual state the following:

> "Note that the default passdb backends require the user to already
>   exist in the system password file (usually /etc/passwd), else the
>   request to add the user will fail."

Source: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbpasswd.8.html

My question is that which are the default passdb backends?

- smbpasswd?
- tdbsam?
- ldapsam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

default file to store pass is trival database file `/var/lib/samba/passdb.tdb`
you can change in by `passdb backend` option in `smb.conf`.

There is more info about password backends: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/passdb.html

default samba need to user exist in system, and check if it exist in /etc/passwd but this file don't contain passwords.